# How to append the same item to a vector many times?

Tags: r, vector

I'm rather new to R, and I've been looking for a solution but can't find an appropriate function. I need a vector of characters in the form:

```
v <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", ...)
```

where `"b"` is repeated 65 times. I know I could do a for loop:

```
v <- c("a", "a")
for (i in 1:65) {v <- c(v, "b")}
```

but the loop doesn't seem very neat to me. In Python, I'd simply do:

```
v = ['a', 'a'] + ['b'] * 65
```

Is there any way of creating such a vector in R, or am I just trying too hard to write Pythonic code in R?

Comment: You're looking for `rep()`: `rep(c("a","b"),times = c(2,65))`.

Comment: `c("a,","a",rep("b",65))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat with the repeat `rep()` function and concatenate/append with `c()`

so `c("a,","a",rep("b",65))` would do this for you

Comment: You could also just rep "a" as well: `rep(c("a","b"), c(2,65))`

Comment: @MrFlick yes you are right. I was using this because OP wrote in his last code snipped ['a', 'a']. So for using his suggestion i also wrote both times 'a'. But i'm with you, it's also possible and maybe even more elegant